# How to perform quantile transformation with missing values?

Tags: data-transformation, missing-data, normalization, quantiles, data-preprocessing

Given are an input vector $I$ with missing values and a target/reference distribution ${T}$. For example:

$I$: 0.215 NA 0.103 0.649 0.057 0.292 NA 0.433 0.521 NA

$T$: -0.996 -0.606 -0.394 -0.090 -0.012  0.361  0.450  0.469  1.179

What is the best way to quantile transform $I$ to the empirical distribution $T$? [Note that $T$ and $I$ (including missing values) could have different lengths.]

Based on @whuber's [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210506/how-to-perform-quantile-transformation-with-missing-values#comment399923_210506):

There are a couple of valid reasons why values might be missing in the input:

1. Some variables did not pass a detection threshold.
2. Some variables were not measured at all.

It is exactly because there are two different reasons that I'm not able to figure out a good way to deal with the missing values.

#### Case with no missing values

If there are no missing values, then, the quantile-transformation procedure I use it is to replace each of the original values in the input with the value from the empirical distribution that has the same (interpolated) rank:

1. Calculate ranks of the values in the original distribution $I$, denoted by $rank(i)$
2. Let $N(I)$ and $N(T)$ be the lengths of the input and target distributions.
3. Replace each original value $i$ with value from the target distribution whose rank is equal to $int[(N(T) - 1)*\frac{(rank(i) - 1)}{(N(I) - 1)} + 1]$.

How should this procedure be modified to make it work with missing values in the input?

Comment: Could you explain why values are missing?  Sometimes the reasons (such as being below some threshold of detection) play an important role in choosing a solution.

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful. There are a couple of reasons why values might be missing (both being valid reasons in my case): 1. Some variables did not pass a detection threshold; 2. Some variables were not measured at all. It is exactly because there are two different reasons that I'm not able to figure out a good way to deal with the missing values.

Comment: In that case it is important to distinguish the two kinds of values.  When something is truly missing, often you don't even have to include it in the dataset.  But when it fell below a detection limit, that's important information--and it can change the percentiles associated with *all* the other data.